# Precision 3260 cannot connect to monitor via Displayport to HDMI

Tags: 20.04, display, dell, hdmi

I have a Dell Precision 3260 with Intel UHD Graphics with three Display ports on the device. I have two monitors. I normally connect to one via Display port directly. However the other monitor has only HDMI. I have tried a Display port to hdmi adapter and the screen is shown on BIOS start. But after it is just a blank black screen'. On the monitor I had it has a HDMI also so tried it with the same cable (display port to hdmi) and the behaviour is the same, with no screen detected. Using the command  `lshw -c display` , I get

```
*-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 0c
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff iomemory:400-3ff irq:146 memory:6002000000-6002ffffff memory:4000000000-400fffffff ioport:3000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff memory:4010000000-4016ffffff memory:4020000000-40ffffffff
```

I have tried different cables. Still not working.
I am running out of ideas. Any ideas welcome